# n-simplex in an intersection of n balls

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, combinatorial-geometry

Consider a $n$-simplex, $n \geq 2$ with vertices $x_i,i=1,...,n+1$. For each edge $(i,j)$, consider $n$-ball $B_{ij}$ such that vertices $x_i$ and $x_j$ are antipodal on this ball. Fix a point $x_0$ in the simplex. The question: is $x_0$ in at least $n$ balls?

**Some notes.** It is impossible to make the question stronger by claiming that there is vertex $i=i(x_0)$ such that $x_0$ is in all balls $B_{ij},j \neq i$. Also, it is not true for $n+1$ balls (there are counterexamples for both cases if $n=3$).

Also, $x_0$ is in ball $B_{ij}$ if and only if $\angle x_ix_0x_j \geq \pi/2$, or equivalently, vertices $x_i$ and $x_j$ are on opposite sides of the hyperplane $H_i$ that contains $x_0$ and is orthogonal to the line through $x_i$ and $x_0$ (and similarly for $H_j$).

Also, this question is a stronger version of [that question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473421/cover-of-n-simplex-with-balls) (Thanks to [Alex Ravsky](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/71850/alex-ravsky) for solving it).

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: "Also, $x_0$ is in ball $B_{ij}$ if and only if $\angle x_ix_0x_j \geq \pi/2$, or equivalently, vertices $x_i$ and $x_j$ are on opposite sides of the hyperplane $H_i$ that contains $x_0$ and is orthogonal to the line through $x_i$ and $x_0$ (and similarly for $H_j$)." -- How do you prove this?

Comment: The first part holds because $x_i$ and $x_j$ are antipodal. The second holds because the hyperplane $H_i$ is orthogonal to the line through $x_i$ and $x_0$.

Comment: I'd suggest you choose another name for the sample point $x_0$, since $x_0$ is already a vertex of the simplex.

Comment: Thanks. I have named the vertices from $1$ to $n+1$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I will use the notation $\mathbf{v}_i$ for the vector from $x_0$ to $x_i$.

Assume that $x_0$ is in the interior of the simplex. (By continuity, the statement will extend to boundary points.) Then
there are some positive weights $w_1,\ldots,w_{n+1}>0$ such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1} w_i \mathbf{v}_i=\textbf0$.

Let us build a graph on the vertices $1,\ldots,n+1$. Let the vertices $i$ and $j$ be connected if $x_0$ is inside the ball with diameter $x_ix_j$; in other words, if $\mathbf{v}_i\cdot \mathbf{v}_j\le0$.

We show that this graph is connected. Assume the contrary; then the vertices can be split in two disjoint nonempty sets, say $A$ and $B$ such that $A\cup B=\{1,2,\ldots,n+1\}$. Since there is no edge between the two vertex sets, we have $\mathbf{v}_i\cdot \mathbf{v}_j>0$ for all $i\in A$ and $j\in B$.

Consider
$$
0 = 
\left(\sum_{i\in A\cup B} w_i \mathbf{v}_i \right)^2 =
\left(\sum_{i\in A} w_i \mathbf{v}_i \right)^2 +
\left(\sum_{i\in B} w_i \mathbf{v}_i \right)^2 +
2\sum_{i\in A}\sum_{i\in B} w_iw_j(\mathbf{v}_i\cdot \mathbf{v}_j).
$$
In the last sum all terms are positive, contradiction. Now we have proved that the graph is connected.

A connected graph on $n+1$ vertices has at least $n$ edges, so at least $n$ balls contain $x_0$. Done.

Comment: really elegant! I was thinking about this problem for a while but could no get a clue of a proof. Can I ask how did you come up with these ideas?

Comment: Gilles: I think using vectors and dot products is standard. First I proved that there is a good ball at every vertex, but this gave only $(n+1)/2$. So I considered other distributions of the vertices. At the end I realized that we have such a graph.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.

Comment: This problem (and your nice solution) was used in problem 5 in the [2015 IMC](http://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc2015/imc2015-day1-solutions.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

This **does not answer** the question. I don't prove anything here but just present the result of some **simulations** that suggest the answer to the question is yes.

My experience make me being careful about my intuition when it is about to think about geometrical construction in more then $3$ dimensions. So before investigating more this question I wanted to check if there is no counter example I could get with Mathematica.
I generated some random simplices with a random point inside and counted the number of balls covering the inside point. For all the tests I did, no counter example appeared. Moreover, the distribution of the number of balls in my simulations seem to be close to a normal distribution.

For example, I generated $1000$ random $3$-dimensional simplices as the convex hull of $4$ random points uniformly distributed in the unit cube. For each simplex I generated $1000$ random inside points with baricenter coordinate uniformly distributed. 
Below this is the histogram of the number of balls covering the inside points considered. 
We observe that it starts at $3$, which means we did not find counter example to the conjecture.

dimension$=3$; number of edges$={4 \choose 2}=6$.
[image: dimension$=3$]

Below I give more histograms obtained from simulations in higher dimension. For each I generated $100$ random simplices and and tested $100$ random inside points.

dimension$=4$; number of edges$={5 \choose 2}=10$.
[image: dimension$=4$]

dimension$=5$; number of edges$={6 \choose 2}=15$.
[image: dimension$=5$]

dimension$=6$; number of edges$={7 \choose 2}=21$.
[image]

dimension$=7$; number of edges$={8 \choose 2}=28$.
[image]

dimension$=8$; number of edges$={9 \choose 2}=36$.
[image]

dimension$=20$; number of edges$={20 \choose 2}=190$.
[image]

The code I used with Mathematica (it can certainly be optimized if you wanna run biger simulations)

```
> RandomSimplex[dim_] := RandomReal[{0, 1}, {dim, dim + 1}]
> RandomBaricenter[dimension_] := Module[{baricenter},
>     baricenter =  RandomReal[{0, 1}, dimension + 1];
>     baricenter =  baricenter/Sum[baricenter[[i]], {i, 1, dimension + 1}];(*normalisation*)
>     Return[baricenter]]
> Distance[A_, B_] := Module[{dim},
>     dim = Dimensions[A][[1]];
>     Return[Sqrt[Sum[(B[[i]] - A[[i]])^2, {i, 1, dim}]]];]
> NumberClosePoints[simplex_, point_] :=   Module[{dim, number, i, j, M, A, B},
>     dim = Dimensions[simplex][[1]];
>     number = 0;
>     For[i = 1, i <= dim, i++,
>         For[j = i + 1, j <= dim + 1, j++,
>         A = Transpose[simplex][[i]];
>         B = Transpose[simplex][[j]];
>         M = (A + B)/2;
>         If[Distance[M, A] > Distance[M, point], number++,]]];
>     Return[number]]
```

and to run the tests and produce and histogram:

```
> dimension = 3;
> nBar = 1000;(*number of barycenter tested*)
> nSimplices = 1000;(*number of simplices tested*)
> list = {};
> For[i = 1, i <= nBar, i++,
>   bar = RandomBaricenter[dimension];
>   For[j = 1, j <= nSimplices, j++,
>     simplex = RandomSimplex[dimension];
>     point = simplex.bar;
>     n = NumberClosePoints[simplex, point];
>     list = Append[list, n];
>     If[n < dimension, Print[{bar, simplex, n}],]];]
> Histogram[list]
```